Excel formula to find the last occurrence value
For Example: I have 3 columns. Column A ( Vehicle number), Column B ( Opening Kilometres), Column C ( closing kilometres). Similarly all rows under column A will be having different vehicle numbers. whenever I enter the vehicle number, column B value should come up with last occurrence value of the respective vehicle ie. closing kilometres in that cell. I have tried the mentioned formula
(=XLOOKUP(A3,$A2:$A2,C2:C2,,,-1))

but the formula works fine only for the first row.
Tried the mentioned formula but it doesn't work well

What exactly do you mean by  but the formula works fine only for the first row.? Do you want to get multiple outputs? In that case XLOOKUP doesn't do the trick.

Row 1, will be having one vehicle number with opening kms and closing kms. accordingly row 2, row 3 will be different vehicles. For example if enter any previous existing vehicle in row 10, the closing kms of the vehicle should come in opening kms cell

So check the range:
XLOOKUP(A3,$A2:$A2000,C2:C2,,,-1),

note I put 2000 but consider how much data you have

Hi, Thanks for the reply. =XLOOKUP(A3,$A2:$A2,C2:C2,,,-1) this works but only for that value, if i put another vehicle number it doesn't work. Kindly help

@Edi Did you try the adjusted one I showed? or just your original? I have removed your original from my answer so you cannot copy the wrong one.

So if I understand correct, this is your desired output:
(Row 2, 3 and 4 are manually inputted, all the rest is done with formula):

Formula used in B5:
=XLOOKUP(A5,$A$2:A4,$C$2:C4,,,-1)
When dragged down A4 and C4 will go up, but A2 and C2 will remain, making sure you get the entire list.
